# Unable to change color of line and scatter plot R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, time-series

I am relatively new to ggplot plot so I think some of the intricacies are lost on me. I have plotted multiple months of data where the data is binned by the hour. Each line is meant to be colored by month where the x-axis is the hour of the day. I am having trouble changing the color of the lines and moved things around in ggplot to try to get it to work but the color of all lines remain black"

Here is an example of some of the data I am plotting: [Example data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u57lutCgPdOxX5ucODboXIrMG8fOO4iDXglKb_o5sS0/edit#gid=0)

Here is my code:

```
p <- ggplot(mtozoneavgk_month, aes(hour, Avgk, group = factor(Date) )) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  geom_line(size = 1)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#DC143C",  "#B22222", "#000080", "#00008B", 
  "#0000CD", "#0000FF", "#66B2FF", "#FF6347", "#FF0000", "#B22222"), 
  name = "Month", labels = c("Sept-2019", "Oct-2019", "Nov-2019", "Dec-2019", 
  "Jan-2020", "Feb-2020", "Mar-2020", "April-2020", "May-2020", "Jun-2020"),
  expand = c(0, 0))+ 
  ylab("rate constant (k)")+
  scale_y_continuous(label=scientific_10)+
  #scale_y_continuous(labels = fancy_scientific)+
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(0.2, "cm"),
    axis.ticks = element_line(size = 2), 
    axis.text=element_text(size=12, face = 'bold'),
    axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", face = "bold", size = 14), 
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 14),
    legend.title=element_text(size=14, face = "bold"), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=3))

p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24),
label = c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24), 
expand = c(0, 0))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are providing ggplot 2 different color scales. First with `scale_color_manual()`, then with `scale_color_discrete()` even though you are providing values in the former and labels in the latter. That's the origin of the error. Merge both in just one instruction and give it a try

Comment: I do not see where you have called color as a geom_line argument to inform scale_color                    geom_line(aes(color =

Comment: @davidnortes I made the change you suggested and the error goes away but the color on the plot remains all black

Comment: As @SusanSwitzer said, you need to include within the aes function the variable in your dataframe you want to use to color your plot. In your case it will be `Date`: `color = Date`  (assuming this variable is of class = factor and not of class = Date. If that's not the case, further manipulation will be needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we simplify your code as follows (letting ggplot2 to take care of colors and labels):

```
p <- ggplot(mtozoneavgk_month, aes(hour, Avgk, group = factor(Date), color = factor(Date))) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  geom_line(size = 1)+
  ylab("rate constant (k)")+
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(0.2, "cm"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 2), 
        axis.text=element_text(size=12, face = 'bold'),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", face = "bold", size = 14), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 14),
        legend.title=element_text(size=14, face = "bold"), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=3))
```

We obtain the following plot:

[image]

**If you also want to control colors** I would suggest to use named vectors:

```
pcolor <- c("#DC143C",  "#B22222", "#000080", "#00008B", 
            "#0000CD", "#0000FF", "#66B2FF", "#FF6347", "#FF0000")
names(pcolor) <- unique(mtozoneavgk_month$Date)
plabel <- c("Sept-2019", "Oct-2019", "Nov-2019", 
            "Jan-2020", "Feb-2020", "Mar-2020", "April-2020", "May-2020", "Jun-2020")
names(plabel) <- unique(mtozoneavgk_month$Date)

p <- ggplot(mtozoneavgk_month, aes(hour, Avgk, group = factor(Date), color = factor(Date))) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  geom_line(size = 1)+
  scale_color_manual(values = pcolor, 
                     name = "Month", 
                     labels = plabel,
                     expand = c(0, 0))+ 
  ylab("rate constant (k)")+
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(0.2, "cm"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 2), 
        axis.text=element_text(size=12, face = 'bold'),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", face = "bold", size = 14), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 14),
        legend.title=element_text(size=14, face = "bold"), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=3))
```

Which results in:

[image]

**Remark:** I do not know if it was because of the sample you gave us but December 2019 is missing so tweaked a little bit your code. Be aware of it when you make your own